# How to prevent form submission if there is not any option selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I am using Rails 4 and in my app I have one form where I am passing form action via dropdown box. Now I want if there is not any option selected then form should not be submitted.

below is my code

```
 = form_for @store,  {:url => remove_multiple_store_path} do |f|
   = f.select(:name, [['Delete', 'delete'], ['Change Status', 'changestatus']],{:include_blank=> 'Select Action'})
   ..........
   ..........
   ..........
   = f.submit 'Submit'
```

I am getting in browser

```
<form method="post" action="/remove_multiple_store" accept-charset="UTF-8">
....
......
<select id="store_name" class="select1" name="store[name]">
<option value="">Select Action</option>
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
<option value="changestatus">Change Status</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit">
```

I wish if there is not any option selected or `Select Action` is selected then form should not be submitted.

For this I have searched but everything is I am getting as result its for PHP and I don't know ajax. So its very difficult for me to understand

If you need more details then just inform me I will post...

Can any one please help me... thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post What you see in your BROWSER not wat u see in Ruby Editor. So people who know jQuery can easily solve your question. See After all Your ruby code will be converted in HTML only. So provide what u see as <script> in browser

Comment: @PratikJoshi : Question is updated... If need of anything else then I am ready to update thanks for your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQs64/5/)

```
 $("#frm").submit(function(event){
 // var valDDL = $(this).val();  
        //event.preventDefault();
         var valDDL = $("#store_name").val();
         if(valDDL=="")
         {
             event.preventDefault();
             alert("select dropdown option");
         } 

 });
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="frm">

<select id="store_name" class="select1" name="store[name]">
  <option value="">Select Action</option>
  <option value="delete">Delete</option>
  <option value="changestatus">Change Status</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @user3814943  You can do +1 if it solves your Question , Thanks :)

Comment: ya I wish but thing is I dont have enough reputations...its required 15minimum but I do have 9 only... You upvote my question so I may get some reputation so I can vote-up yours...

Comment: @user3814943 , really ? :) Check it again u have 18 rep. :)

Comment: @user3814943 , Welcome :) .And next time , if you are dealing with DOM , jQuery , Add jQuery code , no need of Ruby Code .Anyway , I dont know "R" in Ruby ,still I got the solution .The question needed Only jQuery code .So do post it .

Comment: Sure.. I saw your profile.. do u really think PHP is better than Ruby..??

Comment: @user3814943 , God knows , Its programmer Who develops Code , language is just a tool.So if programmers are great then Facebook.com also can be made ,else Regular simple site may be hacked if its done by Bad coder ,he may a Ruby Coder,PHP coder.

Comment: @user3814943 , if you have any doubt , Visit http://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling   ,and Read His profile Info at the right for 5 mins. 5 mins. is not a big deal i think to read Such a great profile.